# Problems with loop

Tags: loop, get-template-part

I have this loop in my index.php:

```
      <?php if (have_posts()) :
          while (have_posts()) :
            get_template_part( 'post' );
          endwhile;
        endif; ?>
```

which calls this template

```
<?php   
 ?>
 <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
 <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
 <?php the_post();
 the_content(); ?>
 <p class="date"><?php the_time('l, j F Y'); ?> </p>
 <?php trackback_rdf();
?>
```

The loop behaves strangely printing out titles and posts in this order:

- Title post #1
- Content post #1 (and this is ok, but then...)
- Title post #1
- Content post #2
- Title post #2
- Title post #3 (and so on...)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`the_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post) function is what advances the internal counter and loads the data for the next post. You're calling it between the title and content:

```
the_title();
the_post();
the_content();
```

You want to change the order and move it before the output of any of the other template tags:

```
the_post();
the_title();
the_content();
```